# Android How to pass value in this asynctask?

Tags: android, string, android-asynctask, indirection

how to pass a Value from edittext to this asynctask (do in background)?

```
public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {
    @Override
    protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {
        mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run(MY_PASSED_VALUE);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: what do you think the `String... message` parameter is for?

Comment: For messages, not for my values(e.g. ip)

Comment: sorry it´s the first time i´m working with asynctask

Answer (score 0):

got it!

```
public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {
    @Override
    protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {
        String myip = message[0];

        mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run(myip);
        return null;
    }
```